# apache jena ObjectFileStorage and TupleLib error handling

Tags: java, jena

When trying out Apache Jena with the following code:

```java
dataset = TDBFactory.createDataset(directory);
Model model = dataset.getDefaultModel();
dataset.begin(ReadWrite.WRITE);
Resource r=model.createResource(NS+"subject");
Property p = model.createProperty(NS + "predicate");
r.addProperty(p, "object");
model.write(System.out, "Turtle");
dataset.close();
```

Jena chokes on this. I am in the process of fixing this and purposely not showing what the content was but I am much more concerned with the way Jena chokes. Two error stack trace examples are shown below.

**Question:**
How can one avoid such error messages? Is this kind of choking often happening?

**Error stack trace #1**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.nio.Buffer.limit(Buffer.java:275)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.base.objectfile.ObjectFileStorage.read(ObjectFileStorage.java:328)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.lib.NodeLib.fetchDecode(NodeLib.java:79)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.store.nodetable.NodeTableNative.readNodeFromTable(NodeTableNative.java:187)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.store.nodetable.NodeTableNative._retrieveNodeByNodeId(NodeTableNative.java:112)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.store.nodetable.NodeTableNative.getNodeForNodeId(NodeTableNative.java:71)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.store.nodetable.NodeTableCache._retrieveNodeByNodeId(NodeTableCache.java:125)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.store.nodetable.NodeTableCache.getNodeForNodeId(NodeTableCache.java:84)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.store.nodetable.NodeTableWrapper.getNodeForNodeId(NodeTableWrapper.java:54)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.store.nodetable.NodeTableInline.getNodeForNodeId(NodeTableInline.java:67)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.lib.TupleLib.triple(TupleLib.java:129)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.lib.TupleLib.triple(TupleLib.java:113)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.lib.TupleLib.access$000(TupleLib.java:44)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.lib.TupleLib$3.convert(TupleLib.java:75)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.lib.TupleLib$3.convert(TupleLib.java:71)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.iterator.Iter$4.next(Iter.java:323)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.iterator.Iter$4.next(Iter.java:323)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.iterator.Iter$4.next(Iter.java:323)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.iterator.Iter.next(Iter.java:923)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.WrappedIterator.next(WrappedIterator.java:94)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.writer.TurtleShell$ShellGraph.findBNodesSyntax1(TurtleShell.java:304)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.writer.TurtleShell$ShellGraph.<init>(TurtleShell.java:147)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.writer.TurtleShell$ShellGraph.<init>(TurtleShell.java:103)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.writer.TurtleShell.writeGraphTTL(TurtleShell.java:88)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.writer.TurtleWriter$TurtleWriter$.write(TurtleWriter.java:47)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.writer.TurtleWriter$TurtleWriter$.access$000(TurtleWriter.java:35)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.writer.TurtleWriter.output(TurtleWriter.java:32)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.writer.TurtleWriterBase.output$(TurtleWriterBase.java:55)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.writer.TurtleWriterBase.write(TurtleWriterBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.adapters.RDFWriterRIOT.write(RDFWriterRIOT.java:101)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.write(ModelCom.java:345)
```

**Error stack trace #2**

```
org.apache.jena.atlas.lib.InternalErrorException: Invalid id node for subject (null node): ([0000000000000000], [000000000000001E], [000000000000003C])
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.lib.TupleLib.triple(TupleLib.java:127)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.lib.TupleLib.triple(TupleLib.java:113)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.lib.TupleLib.access$000(TupleLib.java:44)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.lib.TupleLib$3.convert(TupleLib.java:75)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.lib.TupleLib$3.convert(TupleLib.java:71)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.iterator.Iter$4.next(Iter.java:323)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.iterator.Iter$4.next(Iter.java:323)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.iterator.Iter$4.next(Iter.java:323)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.iterator.Iter.next(Iter.java:923)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.WrappedIterator.next(WrappedIterator.java:94)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.writer.TurtleShell$ShellGraph.findBNodesSyntax1(TurtleShell.java:304)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.writer.TurtleShell$ShellGraph.<init>(TurtleShell.java:147)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.writer.TurtleShell$ShellGraph.<init>(TurtleShell.java:103)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.writer.TurtleShell.writeGraphTTL(TurtleShell.java:88)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.writer.TurtleWriter$TurtleWriter$.write(TurtleWriter.java:47)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.writer.TurtleWriter$TurtleWriter$.access$000(TurtleWriter.java:35)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.writer.TurtleWriter.output(TurtleWriter.java:32)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.writer.TurtleWriterBase.output$(TurtleWriterBase.java:55)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.writer.TurtleWriterBase.write(TurtleWriterBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.adapters.RDFWriterRIOT.write(RDFWriterRIOT.java:101)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.write(ModelCom.java:345)
    at org.simela.parser.TestJena.testJenaFromSimela(TestJena.java:71)
```

Comment: "purposely not showing what the content was"  But NS+something1 and NS+something2 have to be IRIs.  If they're not, then you won't have legal RDF, and there's no reason to expect Jena to be able to store and index it.  Without seeing what your input is, this is really an unreproducible problem, and it's not clear what you're trying to get out of it.  In general, yes, an "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException" is reasonable thing to get if you're using IllegalArguments.  You shouldn't really try to work around that.

Comment: Please note that the IllegalArgumentException is not thrown by Jena but by java.nio.Buffer.limit - it would be perfectly o.k. for me if Jena would explain what's wrong with the arguments e.g. like "illegalargumentexception - expecting IRI values" but that's not what has happened.

Comment: Good point;  I didn't read that stack trace as closely after I saw "Invalid id node for subject (null node): ([0000000000000000], [000000000000001E], [000000000000003C])" in the second one.  Still, it would be easier to describe what's going on here and whether it's typical if we knew what it is that can't be indexed correctly here.  Note that in [ObjectFileStorage](https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/master/jena-tdb/src/main/java/com/hp/hpl/jena/tdb/base/objectfile/ObjectFileStorage.java#L306), there *are* some more meaningful messages;  I wonder if the Java infrastructure is catching some...

Comment: ...and rewrapping them in ways that you don't get to see as much of the message.

Comment: I' have changed the question to show that a simple subject predicate object example was used may be with a broken Namespace.

Comment: But we still don't know what NS is, so we have no idea whether the IRIs are legal or not.