# Jena RDF model union method

Tags: graph, rdf, jena

I am a newbie of Jena, I am now using Jean to constuct some interesting user graphs, including person entites and some of their relations, however, when I use `Model` interface of Jena, I always run into exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.atlas.lib.InternalErrorException: Invalid id node for object (null node): ([0000000000B5C8BA], [00000000000002E2], [0000000000B5C91A])
    at org.apache.jena.tdb.lib.TupleLib.triple(TupleLib.java:109)
    at org.apache.jena.tdb.lib.TupleLib.triple(TupleLib.java:84)
    at org.apache.jena.tdb.lib.TupleLib.lambda$convertToTriples$2(TupleLib.java:54)
    at org.apache.jena.tdb.lib.TupleLib$$Lambda$43/54162225.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.iterator.Iter$2.next(Iter.java:270)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.iterator.Iter$2.next(Iter.java:270)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.iterator.Iter$2.next(Iter.java:270)
    at org.apache.jena.atlas.iterator.Iter.next(Iter.java:891)
    at org.apache.jena.util.iterator.WrappedIterator.next(WrappedIterator.java:94)
    at org.apache.jena.util.IteratorCollection.iteratorToList(IteratorCollection.java:63)
    at org.apache.jena.graph.GraphUtil.addIteratorWorker(GraphUtil.java:144)
    at org.apache.jena.graph.GraphUtil.addInto(GraphUtil.java:139)
    at org.apache.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.add(ModelCom.java:225)
    at org.apache.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.union(ModelCom.java:1502)
```

This exceptions occurs whenever I try to use `union` method in `Model` interface, say:

```
val newModel = model_1.union(model_2)
```

Could someone give some hint ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like this is not uncommon. There is still some research for you to do: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28671443/1531971

Comment: The usual cause for this is updateing with transactions and not sync'ing on program exit.  Use transactions. https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/tdb_transactions.html